# Launch a Kubernetes job with Python and the AWS CLI installed on the container?

Tags: python, kubernetes

I'm trying to configure a Kubernetes job to run a set of bash and python scripts that contains some AWS CLI commands.

Is there a good image out there for doing that?  Do I need to create a custom docker image?  I just want a container with these tools installed, what's the easiest way of getting there?

Comment: Just start with one of the base python images and add awscli to it.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest would be getting any image from Docker hub containing AWS CLI, for example [`woahbase/alpine-awscli`](https://hub.docker.com/r/woahbase/alpine-awscli).

You can use it in a following way `kubectl run aws-cli --image=woahbase/alpine-awscli`

This would create a `pod` names aws-cli which would contain following image.
You would need to upload your scripts to the `pod` or mount a storage [Configure a Pod to Use a PersistentVolume for Storage](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-persistent-volume-storage/).

Keep in mind this is not recommended as this image does not belong to you and you have no idea if there were no changes before checking.

I would create my own Docker hub repo and build my own image, something like the following:

```
FROM alpine:3.6
RUN apk -v --update add \
        python \
        py-pip \
        groff \
        less \
        mailcap \
        && \
    pip install --upgrade awscli==1.14.5 s3cmd==2.0.1 python-magic && \
    apk -v --purge del py-pip && \
    rm /var/cache/apk/*
VOLUME /root/.aws
VOLUME /project
WORKDIR /project
ENTRYPOINT ["aws"]
```